# Large numbers in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, largenumber

Why this works

```
select 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000*9 from dual --41 digit number
```

Output:

```
90000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

but this gives uncorrect result

```
select 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000+1 from dual --41 digit number
```

Output:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I cant understand why Oracle can multiply a large number by 9 but fail to add 1 to it !

Comment: Internally float is used here. Easy to multiply, hard to add 1.

Comment: OCINumber format can store up to 38 valid decimal digits(theoretically 40) the rest is exponent. Oracle does not use floats internaly but uses BCD code. See http://www.ixora.com.au/notes/number_representation.htm

Comment: Thank you friends, I didnt get it, i dont think that issue of internal storage since its calculated in memory, what do you think ? can you please write an well explained answers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments are hinting at, you are hitting the limits of Oracle's number precision.  In other words, Oracle has a limit of significant digits it can handle (even in memory) before being forced to perform some rounding and start losing precision, which is exactly what you observed.

Although your example makes the behavior seem counter-intuitive, it does make sense if we illustrate it by seeing how we would translate these numbers into scientific notation.

So for the number `10000000000000000000000000000000000000000`, it can be represented concisely in the following form: `1E+40`.

However, in order to represent the number `10000000000000000000000000000000000000001`, there really is no concise way to represent that.  If I don't want to lose precision, in scientific notation, the shortest way to represent that is `10000000000000000000000000000000000000001E+0`.  But that clearly takes a lot more space than the simple `1E+40`.

In contrast, the number `90000000000000000000000000000000000000000` *can* be represented concisely as so: `9E+40`.

So yes, that last number is much larger than the previous one, but Oracle has no problem representing it with precision because it doesn't have many significant digits.

Comment: Nice one. Docs are here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832